# Pythonic way of replacing real return values and implementation of functions with mock ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

My flask+python app pulls json from native binaries via a third party module `nativelib`.

Essentially, my functions look like this

```python
def list_users():
    return nativelib.all_users()
```

However, strong dependency on this third party module and a huge native component is proving to be a huge impediment in rapid development.

What I would like to do is mock the return value of my `list_users` function.
Additionally, I should be able to switch back to 'real data' by simply toggling some boolean.
This boolean could be some attribute within code or some command line argument.

The solution I have currently devised looks something like this:

```
@mockable('users_list')
def list_users():
    return nativelib.all_users()
```

I have implemented the aforementioned `mockable` as a class:

```
class mockable:
    mock = False

    # A dictionary that contains a mapping between the api method
    # ..and the file which contains corresponding the mock json response
    __mock_json_resps = {'users_list':'/var/mock/list_user.json', 'user_by_id': '/var/mock/user_1.json'}

    def __init__(self, api_method):
        self.api_method = api_method

    def __call__(self, fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper():
            if mock:
                # If mocking is enabled,read mock data from json file 
                mock_resp = __mock_json_resps[self.api_method]
                with open(mock_resp) as json_file:
                    return json.load(json_file)
            else:
                return self.fn()

        return wrapper
```

In my entry point module I can then enable mocking using

```
mockable.mock = True
```

Now although this might work, I am interested in knowing if this is the 'pythonic' way of doing it.

If not, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Somebody suggested using `unitest.mock`, but I am not sure if i want to introduce dependency on `unittest`.
Besides, how would that allow me to quickly turn mocking on or off in my dev environment?

Answer (score 2):

You set `mockable.mock` in your entry code, that is you don't dynamically switch it on and off at different times during a single run. So I'm inclined to think of this as a dependency configuration issue. This isn't necessarily better, just a slightly different way of framing the problem.

If you aren't bothered about inspection on `nativelib.all_users` then you don't need to touch `list_users`, just replace its dependency. For example as a quick one-shot if `nativelib` is only imported in one place:

```
if mock:
    class NativeLibMock:
        def all_users(self):
            return whatever # maybe configure the mock with init params
    nativelib = NativeLibMock()
else:
    import nativelib
```

If you are bothered about inspection then there's a potential problem with the extra `self` parameter and so on. In practice you'd probably not want to duplicate my code above or have different instances of `NativeLibMock` kicking around in different modules that depend on `nativelib`. If you're defining a module anyway to contain your mock object then you might as well just implement a mock module.

So you can of course re-implement the module to return the mock data and either adjust `PYTHONPATH` (or `sys.path`) according to whether you want the mock, or do `import mocklib as nativelib`. Which you choose depends on whether you want to mock *all* uses of `nativelib` or just this one. Basically, the same thing you'd do during rapid development if the reason that you want to mock `nativelib` is because it hasn't been written yet ;-)

Consider how important it is that the specification of `'users_list'` as the tag for the mock data for `list_users`, is located with `list_users`. If it's useful then decorating `list_users` is a benefit, but you still might want to just provide a different definition of the decorator in the mock vs non-mock cases. The non-mock "decorator" could just return `fn` instead of wrapping it.

Comment: If I redeclare my class `NativeLibMock`, won't it also require me to reimplement each and every method in my `nativelib`? That means I will have two complete implementation of same methods  - one real and other mock. Seems like a bit too much for something like mocking.

Comment: Another point I would like to make is since this is a flask app, I could always toggle mocking by sending some param as a part of the login request

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer using the `mock` library, despite it being an additional dependency. Also, mocking is used in my unittests only, so the actual code is not mixed with code for testing. So, in your place, I'd leave the function you have as it is:

```
def list_users():
    return nativelib.all_users()
```

And then in my *unittest*, I would patch the native library "temporarily":

```
def test_list_users(self):
    with mock.patch.object(nativelib, 
                           'all_users', 
                           return_value='json_data_here')):
        result = list_users()
        self.assertEqual(result, 'expected_result')
```

In addition, for writing multiple tests, I usually turn the mocking code into a decorator, like:

```
def mock_native_all_users(return_value):
    def _mock_native_all_users(func):
        def __mock_native_all_users(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with mock.patch.object(nativelib, 
                                   'all_users', 
                                   return_value=return_value):
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return __mock_native_all_users
    return _mock_native_all_users
```

and then use it:

```
@mock_native_all_users('json_data_to_return')
def test_list_users(self):
    result = list_users()
    self.assertEqual(result, 'expected_result')
```

Comment: Your point about using mocking only in unit tests makes sense. However, since this is a web app I building, I would like mocking even otherwise so that I could write integration tests between by angularjs frontend and python web server